# mingw32/bin/curl: Argument list too long

Tags: bash, curl, git-bash

[image]

I'm working with git-bash in win7. I have the following shell script in curltest.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

curl -X POST \
  'https://api.ocr.space/parse/image' \
  -H "apikey:#####" \
  -F "language=eng" \
  -F "isOverlayRequired=false" \
  -F "iscreatesearchablepdf=false" \
  -F "issearchablepdfhidetextlayer=false" \
  -F "base64Image=data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjMKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKL0NvdW50IDEKL0tpZHMgWy......
```

when I run this:

```
$ sh curltest.sh
curltest.sh: line 3: /mingw32/bin/curl: Argument list too long
```

How can I get this working?

PS - check https://pastebin.com/jYGm2imx

Comment: How large is that base64 data?

Comment: This is an entire pdf file, so I think its on the order of  >100 kb

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jYGm2imx

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a config file?

-K, --config 
  Specify  which  config  file to read curl arguments from. The config file is a text file in
  which command line arguments can be written which then will be used as if they were written
  on the actual command line.

Alternatively, if it is just one of the -F options that is too big, and you can put that into a file, from `man`:

```
To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign.
```